# cellular network in iphone

Tags: iphone

i have a requirement that to hit the url using pdp_ip0 network i.e.,I need to use cellular data network while wifi is already connected. And So I need to send\receive data over the internet, using cellular data network.so i think first i have to find is there a cellular network connection is there or not. so do you have any idea please reply me as early as possible.

### Thanks

M.Sandhya